# Lucene : getting same length results when querying

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, lucene

So I've tried absolutely all query types in lucene and none of them seemed to work. What I'm trying to do is simple: I want to query the index but I wanna get **exact same** matches. And when I say **exact same** I mean the results should have the same **text** (obviously) AND the same **length**, something that usually happens when querying a database. So for example when I'm searching for **jodie foster**, I'm getting this text as one of the results : **List of awards and nominations received by Jodie Foster**. I don't want results **containing** the search term, I want results that are exactly like the search term.

First of all, this is how I'm building the lucene index:

```
IndexWriterConfig luceneConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());

Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/i_l_g/Desktop/DBpedia/qls_labels");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(path);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, luceneConfig);
while (rs.next()) {
        Document doc = new Document();

        doc.add(new Field("entity", rs.getString("entity"), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        doc.add(new Field("label", rs.getString("label"), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        writer.addDocument(doc);

        }
```

**rs** is a ResultSet type variable and I'm obviously just extracting data from a table and indexing them using Lucene.

Next, I tried querying this index using all types of queries, but I'm getting the same set of results every time, it's almost as if I didn't even change the query type. My last attempt was using a **PhraseQuery**:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
PhraseQuery q;
builder.add(new Term("label","jodie"));
builder.add(new Term("label","foster"));
builder.setSlop(0);
q=builder.build();
```

This is the set of results I'm getting every single time, if it could be of any help:

**Found 5 hits.

1. Jodie Foster

2. Alicia Christian "Jodie" Foster

3. Jodie Foster filmography

4. Impress Jodie Foster

5. List of awards and nominations received by Jodie Foster**

I didn't really think that it would take me that much time, I've been trying to solve this issue for 2 days now and I've visited tens of links and there appears to be no one that has ever had this problem. Please help.

Comment: From your index, are you expecting single exact `Jodie Foster` or multiple possible? I mean, if you have added many exact `Jodie Foster` then you want all or only top?

Comment: no I want them all, but I keep getting very long sentences...

Comment: @AliYahya In your example, do you want only that the number 1 "Jodie Foster" must be returned as result? I think it's better you clarify better the use case. List the input text, the search text (I think this is only "Jodie Foster") and the expected results in order to help you